# Should 'require()' be used locally or globally in NodeJS (ExpressJS)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a confusion regarding importing packages in ExpressJS using `require()`.
I was including some packages e.g. `nodemailer`, `bcryptjs` locally, i.e. calling `require` on them inside functions. So, I had to `require` them multiple times in a single route file.

A colleague suggested that all `require` statements should come only once, either at the top of that route file or in `app.js` file. I'm slightly confused. Can someone please suggest the best way to `require` packages inside middlwares.

**Example Code:**
Suppose e.g. I need to send an email in a middleware function. I have the code for this as given below:

```
var nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
                var mailTransport = nodemailer.createTransport();
                var mailOptions = {
                    from: constants.mail_sender_email,
                    to: constants.user_won_recipient_mails,
                    subject: templateContext.subject,
                    text: subject + ".\n",
                    html: results.html
                };
```

Everytime I need to send an email, I use `require('nodemailer')` statement again. Should I instead require it once in that route file i.e. `index.js` or perhaps in `app.js`?
But then there are cases like `require('ObjectID')`, which are not used very frequently. Would it be good to globally required such packages also?

Thanks.

Comment: You collegue is most likely right, but we cannot tell for shure if you don't show your code.

Comment: [Never `require` Modules After App Initialization](https://github.com/alanjames1987/Node.js-Best-Practices#never-require-modules-after-app-initialization)

Comment: Modules are cached, so there's no performance penalties by including something multiple times.

Comment: @BetaRide added some sample code. Please check if that helps explain my question.

Comment: @BenFortune Yes and thinking the same I use require locally whenever I need. But as @ str suggested, there is an argument to require all modules once and then keep using them later. That confuses me.

Comment: @str thanks for the link. It's very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

require('requiredFile / requiredModule'); returns you the context of the file and expose the exported module from requiredFile or requiredModule.

If you want to use the module at global level require and call it inside app.use(), so that you can use it each time a request is processed.

But if you want to use it locally on for a particular file then require it on the top of the file and cache it in a variable, then use that variable throughout the file (similar to what you have written in your sample code)

Comment: Thanks for explanation Vishal. I'm still a bit confused. Suppose, I have 3 route files, all of them require `nodemailer` in some middlewares. Should I define it in app.js or at the top of each route file?

Comment: If you want to use node mailer in 3 separate files but in every request(as middleware), then require it in separate files.

For example there is some auth module which has to be used at each request, then it will be required in app.js.

Answer (score 0):

Well here is an example.

```
http.createServer(yourCallback(req, res)
{
    if(req.Host == "a")
    {
        require("moduleA")(req, res);
    }else
    {
        require("moduleB")(req, res);
    }
}).listen(80);
```

In this case server will choose which module to use. for example you have multiple hosts, and you create that hosts via js module. so u dont need to import all your host files in to an app. after it is done garbage collector takes it away.

in case u know you are going to be using module a lot. then u just declare it as global module. like fs, http, etc.

Comment: This is useful when we want the code to decide which module to require on which condition.
For conditional require of a file this is fine.

Comment: Thanks Anton, but that explains including modules conditionally. While my question is whether we should prefer `require` -ing modules inside functions or at the top of route files, or in app.js.

Comment: @MohitBhardwaj thne it doesnt matter. preference of style tbh. it is just like namepsaces in C++. you either calling using namespace globaly or you are using prefix all the time. same here. modules are cached and wont hit your memory.